# Recursive Descent Parsing and Syntax Trees

Tags: c++, parsing, recursion, d, abstract-syntax-tree

So I've been researching and experimenting months with language design and I have a much better understanding than I did a couple months ago. I'm still confused about a few things though...
I've hacked away some bad parsers without research but I need something better.
So I'm attempting to write a Recursive Descent parser as I've read it's the most logical one to write by hand. To my understanding each rule is implemented into it's own function. So I think I understand how I would write on of these but only the first half... The job of the parser is to create a syntax tree or something of the like, correct? I've also been trying to research this topic but I haven't been able to find any examples of how a tree is represented in the language. I'm writing in D because it's my favorite language but it's very similar to C/C++ so I will understand any examples written in those languages or pseudo code.

Of what I've seen there's a ton of classes that inherit from each other so there may be a statement class of which the IfStatement class extends for example. But I haven't been able to find how all of this is represented in a tree or even how it's walked later on.

It would be fantastic if someone could show me an example or talk about these things a bit more in depth. Any help really means a lot and helps with my curiosity and goals, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen the awesome example wikipedia has (for PL/0)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Comment: oic... I have not! That helps with half of my question about the recursive descent parser. Thanks for the link Michael!

Comment: Recursive parsers can be created with [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). No need to write them by hand.

Comment: @ceving So are you saying that "there's no need to learn how to write a parser"? What if he wants to do that just for fun? (Also, hand-written parsers are easier to modify and extend. Personal experience.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, I get people like that every time I ask a question similar they reccomend lex/yacc and ANTLR but the point isn't to learn how to use a program to generate it...

Comment: @H2CO3 Where is the homework tag?

Comment: @ceving 1. [We no longer use the `homework` tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated). 2. I don't use ANTRL even in [real-world projects](http://github.com/H2CO3/Sparkling) (for the reasons enumerated in my comment above), and 3. doing it manually doesn't automatically imply that it **must** inevitably be homework. Doing it by hand just for learning purpose is also fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A tree is typically represented as a structure that contains pointers to its children and either it has a `node` member that stores its node type or it is of a certain class so that you can derive its actual type (i. e. if it holds an arithmetic expression, an if statement, a loop, etc.).

A simple example would indeed be the `if` statement, as you mentioned. For that, you would do  something like this (pseudo-C follows):

```
enum AST_Node {
    Node_if,
    Node_and,
    Node_or,
    Node_not,
    Node_equal,
    Node_less,
    // etc., other node types follow
};

struct AST {
    struct AST *children[MAX_CHILDREN]; // don't do this
    enum AST_Node node;
};

struct AST *parse_if_statement()
{
    // expect tokens in order
    expect("if");

    // parse condition
    expect("(");
    struct AST *condition = parse_expression();
    expect(")");

    // parse two child statements
    struct AST *then_branch = parse_statement();
    struct AST *else_branch = NULL;
    if (accept("else")) {
        else_branch = parse_statement();
    }

    // create AST, fill in children
    struct AST *if_statement = new_AST_node(Node_if);
    if_statement->children[0] = condition;
    if_statement->children[1] = then_branch;
    if_statement->children[2] = else_branch;

    return if_statement;
}
```

So basically you just expect/accept the permanent lexical elements ("if", parentheses around the condition, etc.), then you hand the parsing of the subtrees (the condition and the two branches) to the appropriate parser functions.

And this is how you walk the tree: you basically do a **depth-first walk,** compiling or interpreting each child in order. Then you add the extra semantics that the node type of the subtree currently being interpreted/compiled implies.

```
Value *interpret_if_statement(struct AST *ast)
{
    assert(ast->node == Node_if);

    struct AST *condition = ast->children[0];
    struct AST *then_branch = ast->children[1];
    struct AST *else_branch = ast->children[2];

    // evaluate condition
    Value *condval = interpret_expression(condition);

    if (condval->bool_value == TRUE) {
        // if condition is true, interpret "then" branch
        return interpret_statement(then_branch);
    } else if (else_branch != NULL) {
        // otherwise interpret "else" branch, if any
        return interpret_statement(else_branch);
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense! So the tree is essentially made up of instances of the AST struct? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @APott Yes, but if you don't yet know about a typical tree implementation in C (C++, D...), then I suggest you study those a bit. It's really as simple as having some pointers to the children.

Comment: @APott Also, if you want a real implementation that works (compiles and runs) out of the box, have a look at [the scripting language I've created](http://github.com/H2CO3/Sparkling/tree/master/src/parser.c).

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help! I will definitely look into it and try some things.

Comment: Well deserved, thanks again! Your project interests me also, I will dig into later on probably :P

Comment: @APott I hope you'll find it useful (that's my goal with it anyway).